# Registered URLs in a router not working

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am attempting to have several views in a router that is used in a url, and the urls don't seem to work at all. I followed the instructions on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/, but my code doesn't appear to work.

My intention is to be able to access the views through these urls:

```
/rest-api/clubs/  
/rest-api/users/  
/rest-api/token/  
/rest-api/docs/
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as rest_views
from rest_framework import routers

# These urls don't work at all. But if I put them directly in urlpatterns,
# instead of a router, they work.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clubs', views.ClubViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'token', rest_views.obtain_auth_token, base_name="User Token (login)")
router.register(r'docs', include_docs_urls(), base_name="API Documentation")

urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Homepage"),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

#### views.py

```
from .models import Club, Token, Calendar
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
class ClubViewSet(viewsets.views.APIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.views.APIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was using `APIView` in **views.py**. Changing it to `ModelViewSet` fixed the issue.

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class ClubViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
     ……,
    url(r'^register_route', include(router.urls),name='register_route'), //this is important
    url(r'^ap_auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'),name='ap_auth')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Router` only works with `ViewSet`. That means that:

```
router.register(r'clubs', views.ClubViewSet)  # OK
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)  # OK
router.register(r'token', rest_views.obtain_auth_token, base_name="User Token (login)")  # NOK, it's not a viewset
router.register(r'docs', include_docs_urls(), base_name="API Documentation")  # NOK, includes don't work.
```

The two last lines should go into the urlpatterns directly.

Comment: Alright I changed that, but I'm still having the same issue with `clubs` and `users`